Create a MySQL statement joining multiple tables and doing a calculation after retrieving SUM, COUNT or NULL results
How do I create a SQL statement to paginate users calculated performance results?
Users
usersid | name etc...
1 | Satoshi
2 | Musk

Lessons with amounts
lessonsid | usersid | totalPay
1 | 1 | 200
2 | 1 | 375

Jobs
jobsid | usersid..
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 1
4 | 1
5 | 1

Job offers
offersid | usersid..
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 1
4 | 1
5 | 1
6 | 1
7 | 1
8 | 1
9 | 1

Query description:
SELECT users.*,
  'get all users',
  'The SUM(totalPay) FROM lessons, if there are no lessons then return 0 - AS totalSum',
  'The COUNT(jobid) FROM jobs WHERE usersid=id, if there are no jobs then return 0 - AS greens',
  'The COUNT(id) FROM offers WHERE usersid=id, if there are no offers then return 0 - AS golds'
FROM
  users
LEFT JOIN
  'Left join tables USING usersid? I need all the data from the users table regardless of whether there is data available in the joined tables. If there is no data in the joined tables then variables need to have a zero int value as in the SELECT statement'
  'lessons'
  'jobs'
  'offers'

DO CALCULATION - Calculate a score for the user (I have used php as an example)
  'user_score = 0;
  if (greens>0 && golds>0){
     user_score = (greens/golds) * totalSum;
     user_score = round(user_score);
  }'

ORDER BY user_score DESC

Desired result:
userid: 1 greens=5, golds=9, totalsum=575 -> user_sore=5/9*575=319
userid: 2 user_sore=0

usersid | user_score | name etc
1 | 319 | Satoshi
2 | 0 | Musk


You simply need to join all the table and need to put final calculation at the final select statement like below -
SELECT U.usersid, COALESCE(ROUND(job_count/job_offer_count*total_pay), 0) user_score, name
  FROM USERS U
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT usersid, SUM(totalPay) total_pay
               FROM LESSONS
              GROUP BY usersid) L ON U.usersid = L.usersid
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT usersid, COUNT(*) job_count
               FROM JOBS
              GROUP BY usersid) J ON U.usersid = J.usersid
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT usersid, COUNT(*) job_offer_count
               FROM JOB_OFFERS
              GROUP BY usersid) JO ON U.usersid = JO.usersid;

Demo.

GROUP BY before JOIN - the safe way!

Brilliant, works great thanks!

This is an SQL that you try to write based on your needs, but since there is no DDL, the corresponding table is not created for testing
select
    usersid,
    name,
    if (
            greens > 0 and golds > 0,
            round((greens/golds)*totalSum),
            0
    ) as user_score
from (
         select
             u.usersid,
             u.name,
             ifnull(l.totalPay, 0) as totalSum,
             ifnull(count(distinct j.jobsid), 0) as greens,
             ifnull(count(distinct o.offersid), 0) as golds
         from users u
                  left join (select usersid, sum(totalPay) totalPay from lessons group by usersid) l on l.usersid = u.usersid
                  left join jobs j on j.usersid = u.usersid
                  left join offers o on o.usersid = u.usersid
         group by usersid
) mid
order by user_score desc


The SUM() will be multiplied by the number of matches in the cross product of all the tables.

@Barmar You're right, for totalSum have to use a subquery before joining the table
